# Selenium Standalone Webdrivers lookup to local host instead of github external site

Tags: github, selenium-webdriver, wdio

Currently we run into an issue when weddriverio execution launches browsers it is getting failed due to the external github website restricted or blocked in our corporate network. So we are planning to look up the drivers instead of external github website to localhost repo or local driver location similar to selenium how it launched the browsers. So is there any possible solution to confiugure the local host instead of external github website ?

I attempted browser launch through wdio execution and got the below error.

```
2023-09-12T06:37:52.655Z ERROR @wdio/selenium-standalone-service: 
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 185.199.111.153:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)
```

From our research found that the above github IP blocked due to malicious records on it. So we are trying to replace the github external site to local drivers location to get rid of this issue. Please help us to change the necessary code base or solution to fix this.